# Unity Particle Emitter - connect particles

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make particles like this:
https://ak2.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/6575432/preview/stock-footage-plexus-background.mp4

The only problem is that I cannot connect particles

Anyone have idea how to do it ?

Comment: I don't think any particle in that image. I only see lines connected to points....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw lines between particles by looping through them and using [LineRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html)  `lineRenderer.SetPosition(particle[0].transform.position, particle[1].transform.position);`

This of course would not be an "instant" effect as the particles would not be emitted in a connected state - they are being emitted from the particle emitter one at a time, and therefore would need to be connected one at a time (or in timed bursts). With many many particles and multiple connections per particle I would imagine this operation could take some time - you might want to consider something other than the particle emmitter if this doesn't adequately achieve the effect you are looking for.

[Look here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.GetParticles.html) for some relevant documentation on getting the particles.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it